# Django Template loader searching template in another app

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

The template loader is searching  template file in another app instead of current app. Tn this case, template loader should search in home/templates directory instead its searching template in polls/template directory . Please help

[my code](https://ibb.co/1fCj2dM)

[template loader post-mortem](https://ibb.co/V9Y25Zh)

Comment: is home in installed apps?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you maybe edit your question and paste the code inside a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) instead of linking to an external screenshot?

Comment: thanks, it was not in installed apps, i added and it  worked

Answer (score 1):

Please add your app in installed apps in **settings.py** file. I suggest doing the following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home',
]
```